# Trying to read first email with VB.net using IMAP

Tags: vb.net, email

I am trying to read the first email in VB.net using IMAP

This is the code I have:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.IO
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Text

Public Class Algebra

    Dim TC As TcpClient
    Dim NS As NetworkStream
    Dim SW As StreamWriter
    Dim SR As StreamReader

 Sub GetEmail()
        TC = New TcpClient("outlook.office365.com", 993)
        NS = TC.GetStream()
        SW = New StreamWriter(NS)
        SR = New StreamReader(NS)
        Dim d(TC.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        NS.Read(d, 0, CInt(d.Length))'******Hangs here...
        Dim r As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(d).TrimEnd()
        SW.WriteLine("$ LOGIN me@myschool.school.nz MyPassword")'**Changed for security...
        SW.Flush()
        NS.Read(d, 0, CInt(d.Length))
        r = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(d).TrimEnd()
        SW.WriteLine("$ FETCH 0 body[text]") '0 is index...
        SW.Flush()
        NS.Read(d, 0, CInt(d.Length))
        MsgBox(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(d).TrimEnd())
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I run this it gets as far as the NS.Read statement, taking too long to respond (appears to be hanging due to an error?) and then simply returns all zeros as the response. Any ideas what is wrong? Might be something simple I assume?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 2):

This has been so frustrating. First of all, I needed to use SSL (has to change the code). Then it still didn't work. Finally then found out that the "\r\n" does not work with VB.net only c...

Here is how I finally got it to work for Outlook 365 (Mic Exchange)!

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Net.Security
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Text

Public Class MyClass
    Dim Tcp As TcpClient
    Dim Ssl As SslStream

    Sub GetEmail() 'Read email (IMAP) with SSL
        Tcp = New TcpClient()
        Tcp.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 993)
        Ssl = New SslStream(Tcp.GetStream())
        Ssl.AuthenticateAsClient("outlook.office365.com")
        Dim r As String = Stream()
        r = Stream(". LOGIN you@youraddr password")
        r = Stream(". SELECT INBOX") 'Need this before doing a FETCH
        r = Stream(". SEARCH FROM Iwant@fromthisperson.com") 'enumerates all emails that are from this addr
        r = Stream(". FETCH 79 (BODY[TEXT])") 'Where 79 is the email number...
        r = Stream() 'Need this to get the OK back...
        'See the other IMAP commands available at https://www.skytale.net/blog/archives/23-Manual-IMAP.html
        r = Stream(". LOGOUT")
        Ssl.Dispose()
        Tcp.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Function Stream(Optional a As String = "")
        If a <> "" Then Ssl.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a & vbCrLf))
        Dim data(65536) As Byte
        Dim bytes As Integer = Ssl.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
        Dim r As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)
        Return Strings.Right(r, Len(r) - 2) 'Removes prefix "* " or ". " - You might want to keep this...
    End Function
End Class
```

That's all u need! I am writing this because of so much unnecessary proprietary software trying to make money on this... Let me know if it was useful...